# WinDbg !name2ee not returning JITTED code address

Tags: windbg

After attaching to a process and loading `sos.dll`:

```
.load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll
```

I next run:

```
!name2ee System_Windows_Forms_ni System.Windows.Forms.Application+MarshalingControl..ctor
```

But it does not return the JITTED code address anymore.
No errors either, just does nothing, no output.

Strange thing is, it worked fine before Thursday of last week, and I'm not aware of any changes made to the Windows environment during that time.

Can anyone suggest what I should look for to resolve the issue?

We have an application crash we are trying to troubleshoot, and the vendor is needing information from WinDBG, but I'm unable to set the breakpoint since I can't get the JITTED address.

Comment: "i'm unable to set the breakpoint since i can't get the JITTED address", why cannot you use `!bpmd`? https://kiewic.com/2015-10-11/set-a-breakpoint-in-managed-code-cs-using-windbg

Comment: How did you make sure that method was jitted?